# how does %lookup decides what search method to use

Tags: rpgle

Statement below comes from this link:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-lookupxx-look-up-array-element

*"The %LOOKUPxx built-in functions use a binary search for sequenced arrays (arrays that have the ASCEND or DESCEND keyword specified)"*.

Example code below comes from this link: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=structures-array-data

```
DCL-DS families QUALIFIED DIM(10);
   name VARCHAR(25);
   num_children INT(10);
   DCL-DS children DIM(5);
      name VARCHAR(25);
      age INT(10);
   END-DS;
END-DS;

SORTA families(*).name;
IF %LOOKUP('Smith' : families(*).name);
   ...
ENDIF;
```

Since there is no ascend or descend keyword on the families.name field, the %lookup will use the sequential search (not binary search) to perform lookup?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as documented in your question the array definition must have `ASCEND` or `DESCEND` specified before `%lookup()` will use a binary search.

Note that the use of the keywords for an [array loaded at run-time](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=keywords-ascend) do not ensure that the data is ordered.  You'd still need to use the `SORTA` op-code.

> A prerun-time array or table is checked for the specified sequence at
> the time the array or table is loaded with data. If the array or table
> is out of sequence, control passes to the RPG IV exception/error
> handling routine. A run-time array (loaded by input and/or calculation
> specifications) is not sequence checked.

If you have a run-time array with the `ASCEND` or `DESCEND` keywords specified and you don't sort it prior to using the `%lookup()` functions, then you may get  incorrect results.

Comment: The example code does a SORTA and then %lookup, which makes me second guess myself (Thinking, maybe RPGLE is smart enough to see that SORTA was called and use the binary search for the lookup).  If sequential search is used, the SORTA in this example seems redundant.

Comment: That would be nice, but as far as I know that is not (currently) the case.  RPG's not known for it's collection of run-time meta-data.  Though it is improving...

Comment: Unfortunately, in your case, if you want %lookup to use a binary search, you'll have to do an "array of keys"

dcl-s name VARCHAR(25) ascend;

which will be filled with the values of the corresponding structure field. Then, in parallel, sort the array of structures and the array of keys by the same field.
And after that, use %lookup on the array of keys and take an element from the array of structures by the resulting index.